# Create vCard files from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, vcf-vcard

```
ListDict=[
        
        {key1:val1, key2:val2, key3:val3, key4:val4, key5:val5}
        {key1:val6, key2:val7, key3:val8, key4:val9, key5:val10}
        {key1:val11, key2:val12, key3:val13, key4:val14, key5:val5}
        {key1:val16, key2:val17, key3:val18, key4:val19, key5:val20}
        {key1:val21, key2:val22, key3:val23, key4:val24, key5:val25}
        {key1:val26, key2:val27, key3:val28, key4:val29, key5:va30}
]

v = vobject.vCard()
v.add('cn').value = val1
v.add('n').value = val2
v.add('fn').value = val3
v.add('title').value = val4
v.add('email').value = val5
v.serialize()
```

I have a list of dictionaries, and i want to iterate inside the list and then inside each dictionary inside it, and my problem is to go to value the fields of each vCard files - thanks to the implementation of the vobject library that allow me to create a vCard.
I would like to create a vCard by adding the data of each dictionary that is present in the list, but i don't how to do it, because each dictionary has the same key string, but each key of each dictionary has associated different value, that is, also in this case a string.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import vobject


key1, key2, key3, key4, key5 = [i for i in range(5)]
val1, val3, val4, val5 = [str(i) for i in range(5, 9)]
val2 = '123 456'

ListDict = [
    {key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3, key4: val4, key5: val5},
    {key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3, key4: val4, key5: val5},
    {key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3, key4: val4, key5: val5},
    {key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3, key4: val4, key5: val5},
    {key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3, key4: val4, key5: val5},
    {key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3, key4: val4, key5: val5},
]

for line in ListDict:
    v = vobject.vCard()
    o = v.add('cn')
    o.value = line[key1]

    o = v.add('n')
    o.value = vobject.vcard.Name(
        family=line[key2].split()[-1],
        given=line[key2].split()[0]
    )

    o = v.add('fn')
    o.value = line[key3]

    o = v.add('title')
    o.value = line[key4]

    o = v.add('email')
    o.value = line[key5]
    print(v.serialize())
```

Result:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
CN:5
EMAIL:8
FN:6
N:456;123;;;
TITLE:7
END:VCARD

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
CN:5
EMAIL:8
FN:6
N:456;123;;;
TITLE:7
END:VCARD

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
CN:5
EMAIL:8
FN:6
N:456;123;;;
TITLE:7
END:VCARD

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
CN:5
EMAIL:8
FN:6
N:456;123;;;
TITLE:7
END:VCARD

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
CN:5
EMAIL:8
FN:6
N:456;123;;;
TITLE:7
END:VCARD

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
CN:5
EMAIL:8
FN:6
N:456;123;;;
TITLE:7
END:VCARD
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this solution doesn't solve my problem for a simple reason for each dictionary of the list, it always has the same keys, but always different values, so your solution doesn't work properly.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake. Fixed it.

Comment: I try to execute it, but I obtain the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    print(v.serialize())
  \AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\vobject\base.py", line 254, in serialize
    return behavior.serialize(self, buf, lineLength, validate)
  \AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\vobject\vcard.py", line 161, in encode
    line.value = backslashEscape(line.value)

Comment: \AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\vobject\base.py", line 1219, in backslashEscape
    s = s.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace(";", "\;").replace(",", "\,")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: do you understand why I collide with this error?

Comment: You did show a part of code with 's'. 's' is a list, you can't use .replace() to a list. Use ''.join(s) to make a string.

Comment: In my code I doesn't use the method that is indicated in the error log

Comment: The list of dictionary is the result of a ldap query that returns me specific attributes for each user, that are saved, specifically, in a single dictionary for each user

Comment: I found the error: some key field don't have a value associated and the result is a list. Why  I can verify if there is some value associated to the key that are not valorized?

Comment: Now it's working. Be carefull with the types. Use only 'string'

Comment: I didn't catch your last question.

Comment: many thanks for your response.
The main problem is that some keys have no associated value and therefore return as a result a list: [] which in fact is not a string for this reason that type of error was returned.
I was wondering if there is a way for to go through each dictionary and discard the ones that don't have any keys with a valid value associated with it

Comment: You can use `try/except` for each value.

Comment: Many thanks, now I try to modify the code in this way